# How to adjust cell height for picture that is downloaded async

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm setting the image of my custom cell like this.

```
        __weak CustomCell *weakcell = cell1;


            NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postPictureLink]];
    //it uses AFNetwork's UIImageView+AFNetworking extension
    [cell1.postImageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

        weakcell.postImageView.image = image;
        //this method call changes cell height according to image size
        [weakcell layoutSubviews];


    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    }];
```

But then how do I implement

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

method so that it can give different heights according to size of my cell? Because of images size can vary different cells have different heights.

Comment: are you setting only image on the cell ? or is there any other things ?

Comment: Where do you have this code? You should be adding the image to your data source, and then you can query that in heightForRowAtIndexPath for its size.

Answer (score 0):

This is very hard to do. One option would be to somehow get the size from the API you are getting your image from.

A second option would be to only show your cell after the image is downloaded. You can then get your height from the image itself.

Lastly you could reload your rows after the image is downloaded. This might cause a few weird animation issues as your images download.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the similar what you want to do, for this the APIs written will return me the size of the image with the URL, so I know how much size it going to take when dowloaded from server so I give the height according to that.
If you see flickr or any other APIs for images you can see there is an option to get the size of the each different resolution image.

Comment: Actually I'm getting these images from url provided by the Facebook's graph's `graph.facebook.com/[pageid]/feed`

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/
you can use this to get the predefined image size

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that your table view cells can (or should) be reused with the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method, so you don't want to store the images on the table cells.

A better solution would be to maintain an array of images that you can query in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, as well as using it when you configure the actual cells.